# Does Ubuntu recommend any tool for remote desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop

I tried my best to make this an *answerable* question. Does Ubuntu team recommend any tool for doing remote desktop from Mac OS?

Comment: Not really. See: VNC, xrdp, X11.

Comment: I've used `vino` successfully. Haven't used Ubuntu in a while but it used to be included by default. If I'm not mistaken it is part of the Gnome desktop, I don't know if they install it with unity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [Vinagre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vinagre/) (which supports VNC, SSH, RDP and SPICE) and [Vino](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers) (VNC server) are built into the GNOME desktop. Vinagre was integrated as of GNOME 2.2.

Ubuntu also refers to the VNC platform and Vino [in their help documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC):

> VNC is a protocol that allows a desktop to be viewed and controlled remotely over the Internet. To use VNC, a VNC server must be run on the computer sharing the desktop, and a VNC client must be run on the computer that will access the shared desktop.
>
> If you're connecting to a client behind a firewall, you may need to use Reverse VNC instead.

The recurring theme throughout their documentation and releases of ubuntu point to VNC being their recommended remote desktop method.

They also have several alternatives in their [app directory](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/), but I wouldn't necessarily call those their "recommendations".